# What's wrong with the font awesome preloading?

Tags: php, wordpress, optimization, font-awesome, preload

I add some preload tags for my fonts on the webpage and these fonts are running fine except the font awesome.

As you can see from the code, I added all necessary attributes for font preloading

```
<link rel="preload" href="<?php bloginfo('template_directory') ?>/css/fonts.css" as="style" type="text/css" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="preload" href="<?php bloginfo('template_directory') ?>/fonts/RobotoBlack.woff2" as="font" type="font/woff2" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="preload" href="<?php bloginfo('template_directory') ?>/fonts/RobotoRegular.woff2" as="font" type="font/woff2" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="preload" href="<?php bloginfo('template_directory') ?>/fonts/RobotoMedium.woff2" as="font" type="font/woff2" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="preload" href="<?php bloginfo('template_directory') ?>/fonts/RobotoLight.woff2" as="font" type="font/woff2" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="preload" href="<?php bloginfo('template_directory') ?>/css/font-awesome.min.css" as="style"  type="text/css" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link href="<?php bloginfo('template_directory') ?>/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" as="style" crossorigin="anonymous"/>
<link rel="preload" href="<?php bloginfo('template_directory') ?>/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.woff2" as="font" type="font/woff2" crossorigin="anonymous">
 <link href="<?php bloginfo('template_directory') ?>/css/fonts.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" crossorigin="anonymous"/>
```

But the Chrome console throws out a warning for FontAwesome only.

> The resource http://webTest.test/wp-content/themes/myTheme/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.woff2 was preloaded using link preload but not used within a few seconds from the window's load event. Please make sure it has an appropriate `as` value and it is preloaded intentionally.

What am I doing wrong ? I'd appreciated if there's any help.

Comment: did you get any error in console?

Comment: Just a few errors related to Facebook SDK and some plugins, about the font preloading it's throwing the warning I stated above, the preload works fine for other fonts

Comment: share website URL if possible

Comment: You can load from a css using import/